# SQL Query optimization having "HAVING Count(BookedForUserID) = 1"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please optimize query 3 for me. Currently it takes 9 seconds to fetch 6345 records.

Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO @AllTraveler
(T.[ID], [Gender], [AirPassengerTypeID], [GivenName], [MiddleName], [SurName], [BirthDate], [NationalityCountryID], [PassportNumber], [PassportExpiryDate],
[PassportIssuedInCountryID], [TitleID], [UserID])
SELECT T.[ID], [Gender], AT.[AirPassengerTypeID], [GivenName], [MiddleName], [SurName], [BirthDate], [NationalityCountryID], [PassportNumber], [PassportExpiryDate],
    [PassportIssuedInCountryID], [TitleID], [BF].Email
FROM Traveler T
    INNER JOIN BFILE BF WITH(READPAST) ON T.BookingFIleID = BF.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ATraveler AT WITH(READPAST) ON AT.TravelerID = T.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN HTraveler HT WITH(READPAST) ON HT.TravelerID = T.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STraveler ST WITH(READPAST) ON ST.TravelerID = T.ID 
WHERE
    BF.BookingFileStatusID >= 16 AND [AirPassengerTypeID] IS NOT NULL
    AND[Gender] IS NOT NULL AND[TitleID] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.[ID], BF.ID, T.[Gender], AT.[AirPassengerTypeID], [GivenName], [MiddleName], [SurName], [BirthDate], [NationalityCountryID], [PassportNumber], [PassportExpiryDate],
    [PassportIssuedInCountryID], [TitleID], [BF].Email, T.BookingFIleID,  BF.BookingFileStatusID
ORDER BY
    BF.ID DESC, T.[ID]DESC
```

Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO @User(ID, BookedForUserID)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Email) as 'ID', Email
FROM BookingFile WITH(READPAST)
WHERE BookingFileStatusID >= 16 
GROUP BY Email
```

Query 3:

```
INSERT INTO @TempNameAll ([GivenName], [SurName], [Email])
SELECT GivenName, SurName, US.BookedForUserID, 
FROM @AllTraveler AS AT INNER JOIN @User AS US ON AT.UserID = US.BookedForUserID
GROUP BY GivenName,SurName, US.BookedForUserID
HAVING Count(BookedForUserID) = 1
```

Comment: No table and index definitions, no execution plans etc...

Comment: Please add schema with sample data as well as desired output. That'll be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glaring issue to me is the use of table variables. The guideline I see passed around is if you have more than 100 rows, stick the data in a temp table.

Below is quoted from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql

> Table variables do not have distribution statistics, they will not trigger recompiles. Therefore, **in many cases, the optimizer will build a query plan on the assumption that the table variable has no rows**. For this reason, you should be cautious about using a table variable if you expect a larger number of rows (greater than 100). Temp tables may be a better solution in this case.